# Semicolon, comma, vs colon in list of size two

Tags: commas, lists, semicolons, colons

I have a sentence here.

"The different types of switchgrass fall into two categories: upland and lowland."

Can I replace the colon with a comma? Tonally, it sounds alright, but is it allowed or does it have to be a semicolon?

Comment: A lot of punctuation is a matter of stylistic choice. You could use either a semicolon or a comma.

Comment: I like the colon here.  Perhaps a comma would trick the reader into thinking it was a list of three things.  In any case, do not use a semicolon for this.

Comment: The dash is another reasonable choice.

Comment: *Pace* Kate Bunting, I don't think a semicolon would work here. A colon (or dash, as Edwin Ashworth suggests) would be very clear, and a comma would work OK. But personally I think I might prefer to give this information in prose, rather than as a list of just two elements; for example: "Switchgrass has both 'upland' types and 'lowland' types."